# Place Logo, Menu and Slogan over Image Slide Show

Tags: html, css

I need to create an web site header as follows:

1. Logo and Menu on top of image;
   Whatever the image the logo and menu will be the same.
2. Image will have a title and text over it.
   The title and text will be different for each image.
3. The Logo should be on left and Menu on right;
4. Logo + Menu should only occupy a 600px max width (wrapper).
   And that wrapper should be centered on the site.

So I have the following [online example](https://plnkr.co/edit/oUJmR3rlXh6dHpxWpSUN?p=preview):

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

em {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 0;
}

.slides {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide .text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <em class="brand">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40"/>
        </em>

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>

  <div class="slides">

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200?text=100 percent width" />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Slide 1</h2>
        <p>Text of slide 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" style="display:none;">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200?text=100 percent width" />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Slide 2</h2>
        <p>Text of slide 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</header>

<main>
  Main content
</main>
```

The problem I have at the moment is that the Logo+Menu is not centered taking a maximum width of 600px. But to be honest I am not sure the positioning approach I am using is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is `nav` which is `position` as `absolute`, to align both `logo and menu` at center of `slide` at `max-width:600` you need to add `position:relative` to `.wrapper` which is parent element of `nav`.

> **position - absolute** The element is removed from the normal document flow; no
>   space is created for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is
>   positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any;
>   otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block.

```
div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
  position:relative;/*Add this*/
}
```

Thus it get's `relative` to `.wrapper` and align at center of slide.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

em {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 0;
}

.slides {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide .text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <em class="brand">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40"/>
        </em>

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>

  <div class="slides">

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200?text=100 percent width" />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Slide 1</h2>
        <p>Text of slide 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" style="display:none;">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200?text=100 percent width" />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Slide 2</h2>
        <p>Text of slide 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: @Miguel Moura This align Logo+Menu at center just position was needed to change.

Comment: Your code has some problems as the content in the main tag, after the header, just disappears: https://plnkr.co/edit/QLwjGduDLag9crAOTvtP?p=preview

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I did not realized that. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: @MiguelMoura You can check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ze2c2hfz/, as each child element is positioned as absolute and even there is no fixed height or width is assigned to header which is parent block, thus it create an issue and hides all element present after slider.

Comment: I cannot define height of header. That will break my design as it needs to be responsive. Any other option?

Comment: @MiguelMoura Check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b2opLjvp/, your codes were working perfectly fine, I don't know why you have added position as absolute for .slides which is kind-of container for slide. So position .slides  as relative and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your requirement, with some structure and `css` changes:

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 9;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

em {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 0;
}

.slides {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide .text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <em class="brand">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40"/>
        </em>

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>

  <div class="slides">

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200?text=100 percent width" />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Slide 1</h2>
        <p>Text of slide 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" style="display:none;">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200?text=100 percent width" />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Slide 2</h2>
        <p>Text of slide 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</header>
<!-- Main content start here -->
<main>
  Main content
</main>
```

Comment: Your code has some problems as the content in the main tag, after the header, just disappears: plnkr.co/edit/QLwjGduDLag9crAOTvtP?p=preview

Comment: @MiguelMoura, I am not able to find any disappeared content. Can you please address those content?

Comment: Would you like to add `<main>Main content</main>` after `header` ? Because I checked at your question and it's not there too.

Comment: I had the code on my online example but forgot to copy it to my question. I just updated the question's HTML. So yes, I need to have the main tag with more content after the header.

Comment: Added `main` section to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the place where you should put `position: absolute` and the `z-index`. Also added a flex display to be able to center it. Hope this helps!

```css
/* Styles go here */

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

em {
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 2000;
}

nav {
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 0;
}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
}

.slide img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide .text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px; 
  width: 100%; 
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content:center;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  
    <header>
      
      <div class="lobby">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <em class="brand">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40"/>
          </em>
        
          <nav class="menu">
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      
        <div class="slides">
          
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200"/>
            <div class="text">
              <h2>Slide 1</h2>
              <p>Text of slide 1</p>            
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="slide" style="display:none;">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200"/>
            <h2>Slide 2</h2>
            <p>Text of slide 2</p>
          </div>        
        
        </div>      
        
      </div>
      
    </header>

    <main>
      Main content
    </main>
  
  </body>

</html>
```